# How to differentiate " and \" in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a string like this `'"\"'`. The length of this string is 2. So I wonder if there's any way I can differentiate the first `"` and the second `\"`? Thanks.

I'm trying to parse a string and I want to turn on/off a flag when `"` is encountered, but ignore the `\"`.

Comment: You can skirt around escape characters by using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: What is the problem that you're trying to solve by differentiating these characters? There might be another approach.

Comment: @ggorlen I have updated my question for my purpose.

Comment: Thanks. So the string is in the memory of the program or is it in a plaintext format of some sort? I still feel like some context is missing here as to why this is a good solution to some other problem you're facing. There may be a better approach to solve the problem "turning on/off a flag when `"` is encountered" is supposed to solve as well. See [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: It's in memory. Thanks for the link to the x-y problem.

Comment: `'"\"'` is the same string as `'""'`, I.E. `'"\"' === '""'`. Did you mean `'"\\"'`, which has length 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible. The two characters are equal to each other, because the backslash gets interpreted as an unnecessary escape character, and gets discarded:

```js
const str = '"\"';
console.log(str[0] === str[1], str.length);
```

If you wanted to put a literal backslash into the string, either put two backslashes in there:

```js
const str = '"\\"';
console.log(str.length);
```

Or use `String.raw`, in which (nearly) every character gets interpreted literally, without escaping:

```js
const str = String.raw`"\"`;
console.log(str.length);
```